# Why is AJAX POST and GET methods returning HTML instead of data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post, get

Hi I've learnt the basics to AJAX and POST and GET methods but I must be doing something wrong because my alerts return the text from the original HTML file rather than returning data from the server. I'm trying to take in arguments from a text field and send it to the server. The server then sends a session value back to the client. This is just a simplified view of what my code needs to do. Below is my code:

Index.html:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="args" id="args">
    <button id="submitButton"  >Submit</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    $('#submitButton').on("click", (function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var args = $('#args').val();
      $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type:"POST",
        data:{args:args},
        success: function(data){alert(data)},
        error: function(){alert("Error occurred posting");}
      });

    }));`
 </body>
```

Index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
const spawn = require('cross-spawn').spawn;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

//DEFINITIONS
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true})); //support encoded bodies

//Sessions.
app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));

//ROUTES

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('../public/index.html', {root : __dirname});
});

app.post('/', function(req,res){    
    var session = "hello";

    //Adds session ID to args
    var args = req.body.args + " -o " + session;

    //Calls method with these arguments
    runFunction(args);

    //Sends session variable back to client
    res.send(session);
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

There are no errors in the console. I added console.log() statements in Index.js but none of them were printed, meaning the post/get is never reached. I added alerts to see what is being returned and it keeps returning the text of Index.html. What could I be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the code inside the `app.get` block isn't running?

Comment: @sunny-lan I used a console.log in that method but it didn't print to console either. I also commented out the app.get block in case and it still did the same thing.